# Response cookie is not setting in next request header in IE11 browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

Getting cookie from response and set and sending in next request header

It is working fine in Chrome,firefox,safari.

But response cookie not set in next request header in IE 10 and IE 11.